# No logro aplicar bien los puntos suspensivos con CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Es que estoy tratando de aplicar los puntos suspensivos a un "p" con miltiline, me pone los puntos bien, pero no me desaparece el texto restante, no se que podrá ser, pongo mi código para que por favor me ayuden validando que estoy haciendo mal.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 239px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>
  ¿Cómo pedir turno para la sucursal Física desde Bancolombia app? ¿Cómo pedir turno para la sucursal Física desde Bancolombia app?
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que al dar click al punto suspensivo se muestre mas texto este codigo te servira perfecto.

```
<style>
.parrafo {display:none;}
</style>
```

Añades el Javascript

```
function mostrar() {
document.getElementById("mas").style.display = "block";
}

<div class="texto">
<p> Hola soy un texto quieres leer mas sobre mi? <a onclick="mostrar()"><strong>...</strong></a></p>
<p> class="parrafo" id="mas"> Soy el otro texto tio saludame :v </p>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Para que `text-overflow: ellipsis` funcione necesitas dos cosas mas: `white-space: nowrap` y `display: inline-block`

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 239px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  ¿Cómo pedir turno para la sucursal Física desde Bancolombia app? ¿Cómo pedir turno para la sucursal Física desde Bancolombia app?
</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero el problema es que debe ser multiline (3).

Answer (score 0):

Por si le sirva a alguien https://programmerclick.com/article/668468221/
estas lineas hacen la magia.

```
div {
 display: -webkit-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Comment: como eres nuevo deberias de tomarte el tiempo para leer las reglas y normas para responder y preguntar. Tienes que dar una explicación no solo poner el codigo y ya.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/328380)

Answer (score 0):

Hay una solución con CSS, aunque es complejo de entender, es fácil de crear.

Para lograr esto, comprende de las siguientes cosas:

1. `height`: altura `font-size`: tamaño del texto
2. `line-height`: altura de una casilla remarcada por líneas
3. Y las líneas a mostrar

Para lograr esto todos juntos, lo que se me ocurrió y creo que es la única forma, es usar **variables**.

Por eso dije que es complejo de entender. Las variables se usa para tener una sola declaración para todos lo estilos que quieran usar. Solo edito en un solo lugar, y afecta a todos lo que usan.

Las variables se crea y se usa así:

```
/* variables para todos */
:root {
  --soyAlto: 1000px;
  --soyRojo: red;
}

p {
  height: var(--soyAlto);
  color: var(--soyRojo);
}
```

Pero también se puede usar independientemente, para un solo estilo:

```
p {
  --soyAlto: 1000px;
  --soyRojo: red;
  height: var(--soyAlto);
  color: var(--soyRojo);
}
```

En el siguiente ejemplo, está la solución a tu pregunta.
Para obtener 3 líneas de texto, modifica el número de `--lineas`.

Lo que pasa en `height` es un calculo (`calc()`) de las variables:

*`--size`* X *`--line-height`* X *`--lineas`*.

```css
p {
--size: 16px;
--line-height: 1.5;
--lineas: 3;
--paddingV: .30em;
--paddingH: .30em;

width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);

display: block;
display: -webkit-box;
height: calc( var(--size) * var(--padding) * var(--line-height) * var(--lineas));
font-size: var(--size);
line-height: var(--line-height);
-webkit-line-clamp: var(--lineas);
padding: var(--paddingV) var(--paddingH);
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At rem excepturi perferendis aut aspernatur repudiandae, distinctio veniam! Velit ullam, id odit eos, earum optio cum aliquam eveniet totam accusamus necessitatibus laboriosam labore sed deleniti vero sapiente ex voluptate beatae maxime ipsam expedita quae. Fuga esse, sunt adipisci, hic aut veritatis cumque tempore reiciendis quam, maxime placeat nostrum? Rerum et veritatis mollitia provident dolor debitis temporibus, corporis accusantium maiores iste natus. Velit libero consectetur ipsum quidem? Exercitationem nostrum quidem autem assumenda minus cumque! Itaque illum labore quia voluptatum atque non nam quam molestiae perferendis voluptates pariatur culpa nostrum accusantium, maxime sit.
</p>
```

**Importante**
Deves modificar juntamente `--line-height: 1.5;` con `--paddingV: .30em;` y `--paddingH: .30em;` para Obtener el tamaño de padding y separación de las líneas. En otras palabras, no modifiques solamente una cosa, sino, todos juntos; porque todos trabajan juntos. Son variables y calculos.

Esta en tu responsabilidad_

Comment: Si esto fue de tu agrado y solucionado tu pregunta, marca mi respuesta como aceptada para que sirva a otros quienes necesite.